# Irda + vb.net express

Tags: vb.net, sockets

Not sure that this is a valid programming question ... but is it possible to program infa red using vb.net express (iRDA) Got a programming project in my mind, but none of the coding examples work, IrDAClient never gets recognised

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a valid question but it needs to be a bit more specific.   VB.Net can certainly be used to program against IRDA.  There is nothing preventing you from using IrDAClient with VB.Net.

We do need to know though what problems you are having?  Can you post the samples that are giving you trouble or tell us what errors you are seeing?

**EDIT** Update to comments

There is nothing that will prevent you from writing a program targeting IRDA from VB Express.  What you appear to be missing is a reference to the DLL that contains the IrDA libraries.  You'll neeed to add a reference to System.Net.Irda.dll.  It will be in the following directory (assuming your programming to Windows CE)

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE

**EDIT2**

I may be wrong about the ability of VB express to program against a device project.  I don't have any 2008 express builds on my machine to verify right now.

Comment: Copied the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.irdaclient.aspx into vb.net express (the express is the crutch as thats all I have at home) and it does not recognise the IrDAxxxxx classes

Comment: .. PS at this point, it's not a programming problem, it's just can you use the free version of VB.Net express to program IrDA, it's crippled when it comes to services so was wondering if it's the same with sockets

Answer (score 0):

The IrDAClient class is part of the .Net Compact framework. I'm not sure if it's possible to use it on a desktop machine.

You can at least add the reference by searching for the file System.Net.IrDA.dll. On my system it was under: Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\CompactFrameworkSDK\v1.0.5000\Windows CE

If it's not present you may be able to download it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497280.aspx